# Microsoft ServiceBus Receiving BrokeredMessages Out of Order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, message-queue, servicebus, azureservicebus

I have a javascript logging utility that sends requests in bulk to my server which then relays them to a Queue Client (`Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient`). I want to send them in batch asynchronously to the ServiceBus and still have them processed in the order they are placed into the batch I am sending. The documentation for `SendBatchAsync` shows that the method is for "batch" processing. This makes me think I can send it a batch of requests and have them processed as a single unit (i.e.: sequentially). Although, it appears that the messages are getting processed out of order. I'm using `OnMessage` to receive the messages; I'm not sure if this is a limitation or what am I missing?

I get that async doesn't guarantee order vs. other async requests, but this is a single request. I don't want to have to wait for a response before responding to the javascript client as I'm just trying to send them off, but I still need to ensure they stay in order since they are sequential events.

Here is how I send them to the queue:

```
MyQueueClient.SendBatchAsync(MyListOfBrokerMessages);
```

Then I process them:

```
        ServiceBus.TrackerClient.OnMessage((m) =>
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessMessage(m);
            }
```

I don't get the point of the batch processing if it doesn't process as a batch other than maybe making a single request. There must be some way to send a batch and have it process in order??

**EDIT:**
I've tried using `Send` instead of `SendBatchAsync` and I've set `MaxConcurrentCalls` to 1 and yet the messages are still not in order.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn520246.aspx)

> **SessionId:** If a message has the
>   `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage.SessionId` property set, then Service Bus
>   uses the `SessionId` property as the partition key. This way, all messages that belong to 
>   the same session are handled by the same message broker. This enables Service Bus to
>   guarantee message ordering as well as the consistency of session states.

For a coding sample employing `SessionId` and `AcceptSessionReceiver` [see.](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-Session-41c43fb4)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use Sessions here,

1. Set the same `sessions id` to all the messages in the batch
2. Receiving side, `AcceptMessageSession()` will give you a session
3. Call receive on the session (`ReceiveBatch`). This session will give you all the messages in that batch alone.

Comment: Going to play around with this and get back to you :). Thanks!